# CalendarView dialogFragment cropped with smaller screens

Tags: android

On smaller screens (480 x 854) the Calendar only shows the month, and the rest is cut off.

The XML for the fragment is a FrameLayout with the width/height matching with the parent, and the calendarView that wraps_content

The button is pressed to display the calendar

```
        dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {;
            DialogFragment newFragment = new calendarDialogFragment();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
```

Here is the code for the dialogfragment

```
    public  class calendarDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstances) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_view, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BaseDialogFragment and oveeride it's size.
Then make others to extend it:

```
    public class BaseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Dialog dialog = getDialog();
            if (dialog != null) {
                int width = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.8f);
                int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                if (null != dialog.getWindow()) {
                    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Adjust the width/height upon your needs